# cassandra rack replication fixed to (dead) nodes [RF and CL confusion]

Tags: cassandra

- 1 cluster, 3 nodes, in 2 physical locations, grouped in 2 racks
- RF 2
- PropertyFileSnitch
- CL QUORUM

**The problem is:**

First node's (in RAC1) replication is pointed to third node from RAC2 and does not change if that node is down, reads and writes fails.

[image: OpsCenter Screen]

If I start back third node and shut down second node, reads and writes works.

Both second and third node replicate to first node, and if first node is down, reads and writes also fails.

**The question is:**

Is it possible to make it automatically detect dead nodes and point replication to active detected nodes?

- If first node is down, second and third node to replicate data between each other
- If second or third node is down, first node should detect what is active and replicate to it

***Update1:***

Made some tests:

- Shut down first node - reads from second and third node fails (`Unable to complete request: one or more nodes were unavailable.`)
- Shut down second node - reads from first and third node works
- Shut down third node - reads from first and second node fails

Very strange ...

***Update2:***

I think I found the answer. How it is now: 3 nodes, RF 2, writes and reads has CL 2. if one replica is down, reads and writes fails (I tested selecting different keys, some succeeded when one node was down, and fails when another is down)

Now I am thinking to do this: move all nodes to one rack, change RF to 3, for reads and writes I will use CL 2 (two replications will be required for write to succeed, and third will be made in background). So now there will be 3 replicas, if one fails, CL 2 will succeed anyway.

Am I right?

Will writes succeed if there are 2 nodes active, replication factor is 3, and consistency level for current write operation is 2?

***Update3:***

Yes, I think I'm on the right way. [Same question here](http://grokbase.com/t/cassandra/user/12ckcjfh0x/replication-factor-and-consistency-level-confusion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the screenshot it can assumed that it is Opscenter.

In Opscenter there is special feature called alerts. It will help you in detecting dead node.

Now coming to question of node down & read write fails, basically these thing depends in read/write consistency level. Go through consistency levels, you will be able to find out the solution on your own.

**UPDATE:**

May be you might find this [blog](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/how-cassandra-deals-with-replica-failure) interesting.
The only time Cassandra will fail is when too few replicas are alive when the coordinator receives the request. This might be the reason behind your strange situation

Comment: Consistency level is QUORUM, so it should work. But is not working in case explained above

Comment: which one is your seed node?

Comment: on every node in cassandra.yaml all nodes are set as seeds `seeds: "node1ip,node2ip,node3ip"`

Comment: whats is the exact exception message in case of read or write fails

Comment: also what do mean by **First node's (in RAC1) replication is pointed to third node from RAC2**?

Comment: exception message `Unable to complete request: one or more nodes were unavailable.`

Comment: **... replication is pointed to ...** this is what shows me the OpsCenter (in that image). I know that kind of concept "replication point to" does not exists in cassandra, then why OpsCenter shows stat (replication) line to dead node?

Comment: see _Update2_ section please

Answer (score 0):

You want to have all three nodes in RAC1 with a replication factor of 3 and use QUORUM for your reads/writes.  This will ensure that data is always persisted to two nodes, reads will be consistent, and there can be one failed node without downtime or data loss. If you don't care about reads always being consistent, i.e. stale data is allowed sometimes, you can make reads more performant by using ONE for reads.